# Inequality in Inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, inner-products

I want to prove that for $u,v \in V$, $\langle u,v \rangle =0$ iff $\|u\| \le \|u+av\|$ for all scalars $a \in \mathbb{F}$. Here $\mathbb{F}$ is the field of $V$ which is either complex or real numbers.

The ($\Rightarrow$) implication has been proved. What I need is ($\Leftarrow$). I tried expanding the norm $\|u+av\|$ but what I get is that  $\langle u,v \rangle \ge 0$. How do I prove it equal to 0?

Am I missing some small step? Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "for all scalars $a$"?

Comment: Yes. I corrected it

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/706144/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2640945/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\langle u,v\rangle=re^{i\theta}$. Let $a=te^{i\theta}$, where $t\in \mathbb{R}$ will be varied. Then by assumption
$$
\|u\|^2\leq \|u+av\|^2=\langle u+av,u+av\rangle=\|u\|^2+a\langle v,u\rangle+\overline{a}\langle u,v\rangle +\vert a\vert^2\|v\|^2=\|u\|^2+2rt+t^2\|v\|^2.
$$
This implies that for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
0\leq 2rt+t^2\|v\|^2,
$$
but if $r\neq 0$, this is a quadratic in $t$ with distinct roots, and hence the right side takes negative values, a contradiction. So $r=0$, which means $\langle u,v\rangle=0$, as desired.

Comment: Don't you think taking $a = te^{i\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ and  $\theta$ might be different is more general?Or is it a typo?

Comment: No, I want the same $\theta$ for the arguments of the inner product and $a$ to exactly cancel and only be left with real numbers.

Comment: And that is possible because the inequality holds for all $a \in \mathbb{F}$ right?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: Also, a bit clarification for the last step, you want to imply that we can choose $t \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $2rt+t^2\|v\|^2 \le 0$ and this gives contradiction?

Comment: Strictly less than 0, but yes. Assuming $v\neq 0$ (which of course is safe to assume) this is a quadratic with a root at 0, and if $r\neq 0$, then there is another, distinct root. A quadratic with positive leading term and two distinct roots will be negative between the roots.

Answer (score 1):

Let $~u \ne 0~$.
$$ \|u+av\|^2=\langle u+av , u+av\rangle =\|u\|^2+a^2\|v\|^2+2Re(a\langle u , v\rangle)$$
$$\|u+av\|^2-\|u\|^2=a^2\|v\|^2+2Re(a\langle u , v\rangle)\tag1$$

If $~\langle u,v \rangle =0~$, then from $(1)$, $$\|u+av\|^2-\|u\|^2=a^2\|v\|^2 \ge 0$$
$$\implies \|u\| \le \|u+av\|\qquad \forall\quad a \in \mathbb{F}$$

Conversely suppose $$ \|u\| \le \|u+av\|\qquad \forall\quad a \in \mathbb{F}$$holds good.

Let $~\langle u,v \rangle \ne 0~$ i.e., $~Re(\langle u , v\rangle)=k~(\ne 0)~$

So $(1) $ becomes $$\|u+av\|^2-\|u\|^2=a^2\|v\|^2+2ak\tag2$$
Then $~\|u+av\|^2-\|u\|^2 \lt 0~$, if we take $~a~$ as

$(i)~~~$  if $~k > 0~$ then we pick $~a~$such that $-\frac{2k}{\|u\|}\lt a\lt 0$

$(ii)~~~$  if $~k < 0~$ then we pick $~a~$such that $0\lt a\lt -\frac{2k}{\|u\|}$

So both $~Re(\langle u , v\rangle)=0~$and $~Im(\langle u , v\rangle)=0~$, thus $~\langle u , v\rangle=0~$